# Difference between these two lambdas?

Tags: c#, lambda

These both seem to do the same thing.. I'm wondering which one I should use, you would prefer to read, is more efficient, their differences, et cetera..

### Lambda #1

```
synchronizationContext.Post(m => log.AppendText(message), null);
```

### Lambda #2

```
synchronizationContext.Post(m => log.AppendText(m), message);
```

My only concern is that with the second one, even though it may look more read-able, isn't their boxing and unboxing because of the Post method takes an object and message is a string?

Thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong (haven't thought about this in awhile) but I think boxing only applies to what would otherwise be ordinal types.

Comment: @DavidLively: more accurately: value types

Comment: @sehe thus, structs etc. Good call. Looks like his params are strings, so it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are stored in the managed heap, so they don't need to be boxed/unboxed.

Because you don't have do any extra casting (from object to string), I would go with this one:

```
synchronizationContext.Post(m => log.AppendText(message), null);
```